# Compilation errors with target IOS 3.1

Tags: iphone, ios, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

I have developed an application using last SDK (4.3) and XCODE 4. I have tried this application on iPhone 4 and 3GS but always with IOS 4.3 on them.

Now I try to test my application on a 3G Iphone with IOS 3.1.3. To to that I declare "IOS Deployment Target" to be 3.1.

But their are compilation errors for the following pieces of code :

```
UIDevice* device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
BOOL backgroundSupported = NO;
if ([device respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)])
   backgroundSupported = device.**multitaskingSupported**;
if (backgroundSupported)
   [request setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];
```

Compilation error : "Request for member 'multitaskingSupported' in something not a structure or union
And : "ASIFormDataRequest may not respond o ' - setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground'

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(applicationState)] && [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] == **UIApplicationStateBackground**) {
    ...
}
```

Compilation error : "UIApplicationStateBackground undeclared first use in this function)

I do want to keep these behaviors for IOS4. How can I manage to have this compiled for target 3.1 ?

Thanks for your help !

kheraud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that, in your project or target info box, you have `Base SDK` set to `iOS 4.2`, and `iOS Deployment Target` set to `iOS 3.1`. It sounds to me like your Base SDK is set wrong.